# When I use input type=button the value of it is not sent to the server

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

In a form I have a button as input/submit. When I submit the value of the button is send.
if I change to input/button instead and do the submit via `JQuery` i.e. `$("form").submit()` the form is submitted but the value of the button is not send. Why? How could I fix this?

```
<form name="myform" id="myform" action="http://localhost/mypage.html" method="POST" >    
<input type="button" id="btn" value="Actual value" name="save" >  
</form>   


$(document).ready(function() {   
 $("#btn").click( function() {   
     $("myform").submit();  
  }
}
```

Comment: Because you are not submitting the form with the button click.

Comment: It should be a submit button to post the value of submit also

Comment: What would be wrong with the `<input type="submit">` button? Please explain the reason why you want to use jQuery for submitting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Buttons are not the same as inputs--that's why the button doesn't add to the form submission. You could add an input of type `hidden` with the value you want next to the button.

Otherwise you would have to use JavaScript to grab the button after the form has been submitted to get its value.

Comment: Well is there a way to conditionally submit the value of the button?

Comment: you can decide if you want to use the hidden input in the post-processing of the form (the controller or where ever you are sending it and processing the data). Is that what you mean? Could you give an example?

Answer (score 0):

try with this code

```
$(document).ready(function() {   
 $("#btn").click( function() {   
     $("myform").submit();  
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use input="submit" button with preventDefault(); function if you want to conditionally check the form submission

```
$("#btn").click(function(event){        

        if(truePart){   
            $(this).unbind('click').click();        

        }else{
             event.preventDefault();
             alert("Please fill the required fields");              
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try name="Actual Value" , then try accessing the value on server using POST['name'] , it will let you to have your actual value.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your javascript is syntactically incorrect.

Your code

```
$(document).ready(function() {   
    $("#btn").click( function() {   
        $("myform").submit();  
    }
}
```

should look like this

```
$(document).ready(function() {   
    $("#btn").click(function() {   
        $("myform").submit();  
    });
});
```

You're missing two closing parentheses and two semicolons.

If that doesn't help, try this for your button:

```
<input type="submit" name="save" value="Actual Value" />
```

Make sure your server-side code is prepared to accept a `save` parameter, as well. Can't send code to something that doesn't want to receive it!